# Transparent div with large image behind Effect

Tags: html, css

I've looked around but it doesn't help that I don't even know the name of the effect.

What is the effect called which has a transparent div section with a large image behind it. It's similar to a paralax effect but I don't think it falls under that category.

**Please see here:** http://shield.nvidia.co.uk/

At the "All you favourite games to go." section.

I've seen it on lots of sites.

**Another example here:** http://www.wekeroad.com/

If I can at least know what the effect is named I can proceed to learn it.

**Edit:** Thanks guys, I thought it was some fancy effect. It's very simple, I made my own too just playing around: http://jsfiddle.net/uuepunx8/

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.first{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% + 100px);
    background-color: red;
}

.second{
    height: 50%;
    background: url('http://hdwallpaper.freehdw.com/0004/3d-abstract_hdwallpaper_equations_33432.jpg') fixed 0 0;
}
```

Comment: It's just a fixed background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a main container's background to position:fixed; is what you're looking for. Your internal content will need to be big enough to scroll and have something breaking up the content, such as a margin-bottom: 300px:

```
.background{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/) repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Here is a simple JSFiddle to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/pgm6uas4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the name, but that effect is not hard to implement using CSS.

All you have to do is add a background image to each of your scrolling divs (or other element type structuring your page) setting the background-attachment to "fixed".